# “connect: Network is unreachable” in VirtualBox VM

Tags: networking, virtual-machine

Host: WinXP, guest: Ubuntu 12.10, connection type: only NAT.
Kernel IP routing table (route -n) contains only header

ifconfig:

```
eth2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:c6:86:82  
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fec6:8682/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:22 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:4391 (4.3 KB)


lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:16 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:16 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:1184 (1.1 KB)  TX bytes:1184 (1.1 KB)
```

ping of any internet address gives error:

> connect: Network is unreachable

How to connect to the internet from VM? What settings should be in the Network Connections -> DSL (or Wired?)

Answer (score 18):

The output of `ifconfig` indicates that there is no IP set on the eth2 interface. First you need to assign IP on eth2 as

```
sudo ifconfig eth2 192.168.1.100
```

if you want to assign 192.168.1.100 as static IP on the interface. Else use

```
sudo dhclient eth2
```

to obtain IP from DHCP server

Comment: It'd be very useful to add default gateway, DNS if you are using static IP address.

Comment: Worked a charm for getting CentOS 6 to connect from within Virtual Box (Network set to NAT). Thanks!

Comment: `sudo dhclient eth2` worked for me, +1